# Bedeutet "polemisieren" belächeln über jn oder sich ärgern über jn?

Tags: preposition, meaning-in-context

1. Auf [dieser](http://www.arabdict.com/m/results?lang=de&dict=de&ng=de&q=polemisieren%20) Seite bedeutet es "belächeln", aber auf [dieser](https://www.dict.cc/?s=polemisieren%20)
   bedeutet es "ärgern". Was ist richtig?
2. Verlangt das Verb "polemisieren" die Präposition "gegen" oder
   "über"? Auf [dieser](https://www.linguee.de/deutsch-englisch/uebersetzung/polemisieren.html) Seite gibt es beide.

Comment: In dem dict.cc Eintrag steht nichts über "ärgern".

Answer (score 2):

> Bedeutet “polemisieren” belächeln über jn oder sich ärgern über jn?

**weder noch!**

**polemisieren heisst Polemik betreiben**

Wörterbuchergebnis für Polemik

/poˈleːmɪk,Polémik/
Substantiv, feminin [die]
1.
scharfer, oft persönlicher Angriff ohne sachliche Argumente [im Rahmen einer Auseinandersetzung] im Bereich der Literatur, Kunst, Religion, Philosophie, Politik o. Ä.
"die Polemiken Lessings gegen Gottsched"
2.
[ohne Plural] polemischer Charakter (einer Äußerung o. Ä.)
"ein Pamphlet voller scharfer, heftiger Polemik"*

*Polemisieren heißt, gegen eine (bestimmte andere) Ansicht zu argumentieren. Der Polemiker sucht nicht zwingend den Konsens, sondern versucht im rhetorischen Wettstreit seinen Argumenten zum Durchbruch zu verhelfe*n.

https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polemik

> 2 verlangt dieses Verb "polemisieren" die Präposition "gegen" oder "über" auf dieser Seite gibt es die beide

Antwort: **beides wird gebraucht**

man kann polemisieren gegen einen Partner/Gegner oder über eine Sache,
oder beides, das wäre dann gegen den Widersacher.

Comment: _polemisieren_ heißt nicht _gegen eine Position argumentieren_, sondern bedeutet spezifischer _scharf, in kämpferischer Weise, zugespitzt gegen eine Position Stellung beziehen_ Daher gebe ich hier -1

Comment: In der heute üblichen Verwendung ist die Polemik von einer scharfen Argumentationskultur zu etwas verkommen, was mit Argumentation überhaupt nichts mehr zu tun hat - Diskreditierung des Andersdenkenden.

Comment: Naja, kommt ja von πόλεμος (polemos), Krieg, also da kann man auch schon mal härtere und unlautere Mittel erwarten.